# Efecto de Button al presionar un ImageView Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

al presionar un Button en Android Studio sale un pequeño efecto de presionar que sinceramente no se como se llama. Ese mismo efecto como seria en un ImageView??

-Codigo:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/marco_imagen"
                android:onClick="MisDatos"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/misdatos_d" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma mas sencilla es colacando en tu ImageView:

`android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/marco_imagen"
            android:onClick="MisDatos"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/misdatos_d" />
```

Eso da un pequeño efecto de click en el boton

Comment: eso mismo era lo que buscaba man, gracias!

Comment: Por nada, para eso estamos

Answer (score 1):

**El efecto se llama [Ripple](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes lograrlo dependiendo del efecto que deseas:

Efecto `Ripple` que se genera dentro de la vista:

```
<ImageView
   ...
   android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
   ...
   .../>
```

---

Efecto `Ripple` que se extienden más allá de los límites de la vista:

```
 <ImageView
       ...
       android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
       ...
       .../>
```

---

Si deseas que sea soportado desde la API 7 mediante la **library de soporte**:

```
 <ImageView
       ...
       android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
       ...
       .../>
```